# replace placeholders with custom names in a list

Tags: python, format

why `" {} said hi {}".format(["jim","pam"])`  raises an exception
but `" {} said hi {}".format("jim","pam")` doesnt and returns

```
jim said hi pam
```

how can I use a list as argument for the format function

I want to use for the function below (that takes lists as arguments) the format function  to replace placeholders with list items

```
def hi(name):
  return "{} said hit {}".format(name)
```

how can I make this function replace placeholders with custom names in a list

for example for the list `name=["jim","pam"]` to return `"jim sai hi pam"`

Answer (score 3):

> *Why does it raise an exception ?*

Because `str.format` expects as many variables as placeholder, and you have **2** placeholder, and you provide **1** list

---

> *How can i pass a list ?*

Use unpacking `*names`, so each values of the list becomes one distinct parameter

```
def hi(names):
    return "{} said hit {}".format(*names)

print(hi(["jim", "pam"]))
```